# Index page and random posts needs a forced refresh in order to show new content

Tags: login, cache

I have this weird problem with both on desktop and mobile, which requires a manual refresh in order for the index-page to show new posts. It also appears as if the user is not logged in.

Basically, I have a custom login function with wp_signon. The user logs in and get redirected to their "account" page. Here they are shown as logged with the appropriate menu for logged in users. If I click that "Star" menu-button, which take me back to the homepage, the user suddenly appears to be logged out. When I press a post, the user is logged in again. But on some posts, they appear to be offline.

Even if I change the custom login function to redirect to the homepage instead of the account page, it's the exact same problem. Even on the homepage the user is now shown as logged in, but if you press start or type in the website url: www.blabla.com, the user is suddenly shown to be logged out.

When I refresh the homepage everything is as it should.

This is an extremely annoying problem.

Can it be some sort of a database problem?

Comment: What have you done to **debug**? Can you recreate the issue using a core-bundled Theme, and all Plugins disabled? If not, then determine if the issue is caused by your Theme, or one of your Plugins.

Comment: Also, based on your edits: *are you or are you not* using W3 Total Cache?

Comment: I'm not using a cache plugin at all now. The problem persist even when using a core-bundled theme, and even when using wp-login.php. Can I now exclude that there's anything wrong with my custom login script?

Comment: And when you disable all Plugins?

Comment: I get the same issue even after disabling every plugin.

Comment: I suspect that it might be an issue of setting the cookie domain, since I recently added a cookieless subdomain for static content.Thoughts on this?

Comment: If you have every Plugin disabled and are using a core-bundled Theme, then how did you add a cookieless subdomain for static content?

Comment: What do you mean? I've just created a subdomain for the static content. I haven't actually started using it as a cookieless subdomain, I've just created the subdomain, and inserted the COOKIE_DOMAIN in the wp-config.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to describe your `wp-config.php` modifications.